# How do I ouput a large item count (256 items) in a single custom Log.Info field using Log4Net?

Tags: c#-4.0, log4net

I am using Log4Net and have created a custom class for formatting and outputting 
to a CSV file within a windows service loop:

```
private void AutoLogger(uint id, EdkDll.EE_DataChannel_t channel, double[] value)
        {

            try
            {
                log.Info(new Log
                {
                    ElapsedTime = timer.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString(),
                    UserId = id,
                    Action = channel.ToString(),
                    Value = value.ToString()
                });
            }
```

The problem is that the "value" has 256 values for each iteration of the loop. 
I would like to create a loop inside of the `log.Info(new Log` code that loops through 
the values. Something like:

```
log.Info(new Log
                {
                    ElapsedTime = timer.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString(),
                    UserId = id,
                    Channel = channel.ToString(),
                    for(int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
                    {  
                      "Value_" + i = value[i].ToString()
                    }
                });
```

But this isn't possible. Any idea how to do this? My `Log` class looks like this:

```
public class Log
    {
        public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; }
        public string ElapsedTime { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public uint UserId { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just loop it into a string wtih delimiters (maybe even \n) and then log.Info(newString);? If you want to do it alot just create an extension method...

EX:
(Note:this is not tested code I just typed it right here)

```
  string strBuffer ="";
    List<Dingus> dingusList = GetDingusList();
    foreach( Dingus dingus in dingusList )
    {
        \\if you have a ToString defined use it here, else just output all the properties of your object
        strBuffer+= dingus.name+" ,"+dingus.value+"\n";
    }
    log.Info(strBuffer);
```

example of another way to do it here:

[http://www.l4ndash.com/Log4NetMailArchive%2Ftabid%2F70%2Fforumid%2F1%2Fpostid%2F15171%2Fview%2Ftopic%2FDefault.aspx](http://www.l4ndash.com/Log4NetMailArchive/tabid/70/forumid/1/postid/15171/view/topic/Default.aspx)